# How to auto rotate a Street View panorama?

Tags: javascript, google-street-view

How to rotate automatically a street view panorama using the API?

Something like this [Google gallery](http://maps.google.com/intl/en/help/maps/streetview/#utm_campaign=en&utm_medium=van&utm_source=en-van-na-us-gns-svn).

Comment: Use javascript to change the camera angle over time.

Answer (score 4):

You can use JavaScript timer (window.setInterval) for rotating by changing the heading at each time interval. Here is a quick example: [Rotating Street View Panorama using Google Maps](http://theoryapp.com/rotating-street-view-panorama-using-google-maps/)

Answer (score 1):

To change the panorama angle you have to change a [Point-of-View](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewLocation) parameter, namely [`heading`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewPov).
This variable is in degrees (0 is North, 90 East, ...).

Given a variable that holds your [panorama](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#StreetViewPanorama):

```
const panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(container, opts);
```

Get the panorama POV with `getPov`:

```
const oldPov = panorama.getPov();
```

Then replace the POV with the new value:

```
panorama.setPov({
  header : oldPov.header + 1,
  pitch  : oldPov.pitch
});
```

This will rotate the point-of-view by one degree clockwise. Now you just need to use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to have this code repeated automatically:

```
let rotation = 1,   // In degrees
    interval = 100; // In milliseconds

const rotateId = setInterval(() => {
  const oldPov = panorama.getPov();
  panorama.setPov({
    header : oldPov.header + rotation,
    pitch  : oldPov.pitch
  });
}, interval);
```

(`setInterval` needs a function passed to it, in that case it is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions))

Note that the above would probably look jittery.
Decreasing the `interval` will make it update faster, but may decrease performances.
Increasing the `rotation` will make it turn quicker.
Fiddle with these two values and you should get what you want.

To stop it,

```
clearInterval(rotateId);
```

Comment: I figured out that this solution uses a lot of cpu power. My safari warns me of "unusually high usage". Suggestion: There should at least be the option to stop the rotation script at first click. Almost any contampary notebook should be capable of bearing a short cpu usage until the will user act. So this shoud be of no problem. This way the playing engine could be kept as it is. What do you think?